# Access propertyname while looping through an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, iteration, angularjs-ng-resource

As you can see in the code I provided in this question, I try to loop over the properties of an object. All properties are empty objects! I also have another object where I stored a couple of rest-calls (ngResource Stuff which is not important for this question).

Here you can see the "Rest-Calls" stored in **$scope.restCalls**.

```
$scope.restCalls = [
   {
     resource1: RestService.call1,
     resource2: RestService.call2,
     resource3: RestService.call3
   },
   {
     resource4: RestService.call4,
     resource5: RestService.call5,
     resource6: RestService.call6
   },
   {
     resource7: RestService.call7,
     resource8: RestService.call8,
     resource9: RestService.call9
   }
];
```

**$scope.data** symbolizes the data for each **tab**. Every object in this array holds the data for the tab. All resources are initilized empty and if the user changes to a page the resources will get stored here.

```
$scope.data = [
   {
     resource1: {},
     resource2: {},
     resource3: {}
   },
   {
     resource4: {},
     resource5: {},
     resource6: {}
   },
   {
     resource4: {},
     resource5: {},
     resource6: {}
   }
];
```

So far so good. I gurantee that the calls are working fine. In my application there are multiple tabs and so I want to try to implement some lazy loading :D

Therefore I implemented a function:(the index is defined in the html and is only the a number between 0 and 2)

```
<uib-tab heading="Tab1" select="tabChange(0)">
... HERE I have some tables which access the $scope.data[0] data
</uib-tab>
<uib-tab heading="Tab2" select="tabChange(1)">
... HERE I have some tables which access the $scope.data[1] data
</uib-tab>
<uib-tab heading="Tab3" select="tabChange(2)">
... HERE I have some tables which access the $scope.data[2] data
</uib-tab>
```

Here you can see the function:

```
$scope.tabChange = function (index) {
        for (var propertyName in $scope.data[index]) {
            $scope.restCalls[index][propertyName]().$promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.data[index][propertyName] = data;
            });
        }
    };
```

Now lets come to the problem description:

- When I change the tab the **function tabChange** gets fired.
- Every Restcall gets fired correctly

The results only get stored into the wrong property of **$scope.data[index]**. Its always the last propertyname. So for example I change to tab2(index 1).
**$scope.data** will end up like this:

```
$scope.data = [
   {
     resource1: {},
     resource2: {},
     resource3: {}
   },
   {
     resource4: {},
     resource5: {},
     resource6: RESULT OBJECT OF THE LAST REST CALL!
   },
   {
     resource7: {},
     resource8: {},
     resource9: {}
   }
];
```

I think that **propertyname** is not available in the **then function**. But I have no clue how to get the name into this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises because the `propertyName` is in the upper scope of the  function and its value is changed before the function is called. You can bind your variable to function scope like below.

```
$scope.tabChange = function (index) {
        for (var propertyName in $scope.data[index]) {
            $scope.restCalls[index][propertyName]().$promise.then(function (propertyName,data) {
                $scope.data[index][propertyName] = data;
            }.bind(null,propertyName));
        }
    };
```

You can learn more about javascript closures [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and in other sources you can find from Google.

Comment: Works fine! Thanks didn't know how to bind the variable into the **then function**.